How do I create an abstract or base Notifier class in Riverpod?
I have multiple notifiers with similar search and other logic, the only difference being the API call. How can I abstract that logic out? And reuse my Notifier in multiple places?
Example :
MyNotifierOne
@riverpod
class MyNotifierOne extends _$MyNotifierOne {

  @override
  Future<List<SuggestionInfo>> build() async {
    return networkClient.getNotifierOneAPI(query: searchQuery,page: 1);
  }

  final debounceSearch = Debounce(milliseconds: 500);
  var searchQuery = '';

  void onSearch(Ref ref, String query) {
    searchQuery = query;
    debounceSearch.run(ref.invalidateSelf);
  }

  String? getSuggestionLogo(String? name){}

  SuggestionInfo getSuggestionInfo(String? name){}
}

MyNotifierTwo
@riverpod
class MyNotifierTwo extends _$MyNotifierTwo {

  @override
  Future<List<SuggestionInfo>> build(String? metadata) async {
    return networkClient.getNotifierTwoAPI(query: searchQuery, metadata);
  }

  final debounceSearch = Debounce(milliseconds: 500);
  var searchQuery = '';

  void onSearch(Ref ref, String query) {
    searchQuery = query;
    debounceSearch.run(ref.invalidateSelf);
  }

  String? getSuggestionLogo(String? name){}

  SuggestionInfo getSuggestionInfo(String? name){}
}

MyNotifierThree
@riverpod
class MyNotifierThree extends _$MyNotifierThree {

  @override
  Future<List<SuggestionInfo>> build() async {
    return networkClient.getNotifierThirdAPI(query: searchQuery);
  }

  final debounceSearch = Debounce(milliseconds: 500);
  var searchQuery = '';

  void onSearch(Ref ref, String query) {
    searchQuery = query;
    debounceSearch.run(ref.invalidateSelf);
  }

  String? getSuggestionLogo(String? name){}

  SuggestionInfo getSuggestionInfo(String? name){}
}

Initially, I thought of creating a mixin on abstract class AsyncNotifierProviderBase<NotifierT extends AsyncNotifierBase<T>, but it’s internal and I can’t access it.
And help or resources are appreciated. Thank you

Provider family such as myNotifierProvider(Api.one) should be able to do what you want. They are still independent, updating one won't affect others.

enum Api { one, two, three }

@riverpod
class MyNotifier extends _$MyNotifier {
  @override
  Future<List<String>> build(Api api) async {
    switch (api) {
      case Api.one:
        return getNotifierOneAPI(query: searchQuery, page: 1);
      case Api.two:
        return getNotifierTwoAPI(query: searchQuery, meta: 'meta');
      case Api.three:
        return getNotifierThreeAPI(query: searchQuery);
    }
  }

  var searchQuery = '';

  void onSearch(Ref ref, String query) {
    searchQuery = query;
    ref.invalidateSelf();
  }
}
...
ref.watch(myNotifierProvider(Api.one));

Update:
You can also use mixin or extension for @internal class, it is only an suggestion against using it.
you can ignore the warnings by adding
// ignore: invalid_use_of_internal_member

I thought about this. But than how do we get metadata from MyNotifierOne. I think sealed class would be better approach than enum.

I didn't see you were passing the metadata, so a data class is better here. You can also use mixin on internal class by ignoring the warnings
